# Jest - Mocking ES6 classes doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm following the documentation almost in detail (with some simple file and directory structure changes). Using the example offered by Jest to make 'manual mocks' in 'Es6 Class Mocks', I have the following files structure:

```
MyProjectExampleDirectory
│   sound-player-consumer.js
│
├───libs
│       sound-player.js
│
├───__mocks__
│       sound-player.js
│
└───__tests__
        sound-player-consumer.test.js
```

My script to test is as follows:

```js
// sound-player-consumer.js
import SoundPlayer from './libs/sound-player';

export default class SoundPlayerConsumer {
  constructor() {
    this.soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
  }

  playSomethingCool() {
    const coolSoundFileName = 'song.mp3';
    this.soundPlayer.playSoundFile(coolSoundFileName);
  }
}
```

I am mocking the following way:

```js
// __mocks__/sound-player.js
export const mockPlaySoundFile = jest.fn();

const mock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return { playSoundFile: mockPlaySoundFile };
});

export default mock;
```

and my test is the following:

```js
// __tests__/sound-player-consumer.test.js
import SoundPlayer, { mockPlaySoundFile } from '../libs/sound-player';
import SoundPlayerConsumer from './../sound-player-consumer';

jest.mock('../libs/sound-player');

beforeEach(() => {
  // Clear all instances and calls to constructor and all methods:
  SoundPlayer.mockClear();
  mockPlaySoundFile.mockClear();
});

it('We can check if the consumer called the class constructor', () => {
  const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer();
  expect(SoundPlayer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

I'm getting de following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue, however I am unable to get it to work in the **__mocks__** directory:

```js
const mockPlaySoundFile = jest.fn();
jest.mock('../libs/sound-player', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return { playSoundFile: mockPlaySoundFile };
  });
});
```

The code above must be placed before any other code structure, after imports